# xpath br (line breaks) in p (paragraph)

Tags: xpath, line-breaks, rapidminer

Below is an example XML.

```
<p> 
Thisisgood
</p>
<p> 
Thisisbad
</p>
<p> 
This
<br>
is
<br>
acceptable
</p>
<p> 
Thisisfine
</p>
```

I want the result:

```
Thisisgood
Thisisbad
Thisisacceptable
Thisisfine
```

I use Xpath `//p/text()` in Google Doc (=importXML). This results in:

```
Thisisgood
Thisisbad
This           is           acceptable (appearing in different cells)
Thisisfine
```

What XPath would give me the result I need? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve this problem using XPath 1.0. Using XPath 2.0, you'd just do a

```
//p/string-join(text(), '')
```

but this is not supported by Google Spreadsheet.

I'm pretty sure you can use `ARRAYFUNCTION` and `JOIN` in Google Spreadsheet, but cannot help you with this. Better ask a new question with appropriate tags for Google Spreadsheets so people following that tag get notified, and provide an example Spreadsheet using the `ImportXML` function so people can work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used this code

```
=Trim(JOIN("",L3:X3))
```

L3:X3 are the cells

Answer (score -1):

`//p/` without `text()` must be enough to get this: `Thisisacceptable`